# How to continue playing Godus on different Computer?

Tags: godus, steam-cloud

I started playing Godus on my PC. Now I want to continue playing the same game on my Laptop. Is there a way to achieve this? Is the current state saved to Steam Cloud? Is there a file on the disk I can copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some investigation I have found that the Godus is not supported on the Steam Cloud.

But, you can still manually find the save file from your steam folder.

In the game library on Steam, right click on Godus in the list of games in the sidebar. Select "Properties" and then click the "Local Files" tab in the "Godus - Properties" window. Click "Browse local files..."

You should see a "windows" folder or an equivalent folder on the Mac version. Open that folder. The save files are the following files in that folder: (Note: on OSX 10.7.5 the files are inside the user's godus application support folder and not inside any of the steam folders: "~/Library/Application Support/godus/")

- state.back
- state.bin
- And possibly a number of files like statebackup0001.bin
- You will also need to look in the folder named something like prf110000100a1858b which is where the saves are kept.

By transfering these files to your second PC, you should be able to pick up where you left off.

Of course if you do not like the manual proccess you can always use Dropbox to store the saved directory, replacing the original directories on both PCs with Symbolic Links.

Comment: Cool.I will try and accept oft course as soon as verified. THX.

Comment: All files were only in the prf1100... folder. But worked without any issues.

Comment: Here are some info: http://godus.gamepedia.com/How_to_start_over

Comment: In other hand, I can not migrate my saves from Steam to Android. (I tried to copy the `prf1*` directory from Local files of Steam to `/data/data/com.mobage.ww.a1912.Godus_Android/files/prf1`, but it droped my saves)